# Signalr Hub Total Limitation?

Tags: azure, web-applications, signalr

I'm observing high CPU usage when I added new hub (making it total of 5 hubs),
just wondering if the hub total will have impact to the CPU usage?

this happen even at low traffic.

I'm running this on Azure App Service on Standard S3 plan

Answer (score 0):

the issues is not cause by SignalR. 
closing this as already figured the issue

p/s: high cpu usage because of indexing issue from DB